# Does "Jump the Shark" mean a bad attempt when it looked successful?

Tags: idioms

I don't quite get what it means by [Jumping the Shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark).

From [the YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahxG3iPeVcU), it looked like it was successful and nothing is wrong about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of jumping the shark itself is irrelevant, as is how successful it was. The point is that it's such a ridiculous thing to do.

In the case of Happy Days, it marks the point when the show finally completed its transformation from the story of a bunch of teenagers and their family's lodger into "the amazing adventures of the Fonz" with all that implies.

Comment: so in a way, if a coffee shop is failing, and it transform itself to a nice study area with great WiFi, it may be a good attempt, but if it tries to transform itself by showing a shark jumping video or by showing an unknown rabbit figure in the shop, it might be called "jumping the shark"?

Comment: @nonpopularity Sorry but this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

"Jumping the shark" is a reference to an episode of the once-popular TV show 'Happy Days' in which regular character 'the Fonz' literally jumped over a shark. It is widely considered to be the point in the show's long run that the writing quality plummeted and the show ceased to be any good.

The phrase is now used to refer to anything which was once good, but isn't any more. In particular, it is intended to mean that something has perhaps gone on for longer than it should have. Because the saying has its roots in television, it is often used in reference to other television shows that have had a long run but have lost their original appeal.

Answer (score 0):

> Jumping the shark is an idiom used to describe the moment of a
> misguided attempt at generating new publicity for something once, but
> no longer, widely popular

This phrase does not exist in British English. It is an American expression.

According to the link you provided, it has come to refer to an attempt to get people to watch a failing TV show by providing a stunt in it that would not happen in the normal course of things or is out-of-character for the show.

Comment: The meaning has been expanded to mean, *An ostentatious event or display designed to draw attention to something (TV show, store, gathering) that has lost its prominence among the people/audience.*

Comment: The degree of ridiculousness is important for the idiom. Anyone can “jump the shark” when they do something outlandish to get attention but it’s so silly or dumb that it drives people away instead of drawing them   in. A related idiom is “[over the top](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/over+the+top)”.  *The amount of fake blood used in the Evil Dead movies is really over the top, but they haven’t jumped the shark yet.*

Comment: "The phrase does not exist in British English" - once, I might have disagreed, but I recently used the expression to a colleague (who seems pretty US-media-savvy - he loves trashy Hollywood B movies) and he gaped and said "What?". The Guardian assumes its readers are familiar enough with the phrase to grasp the intent of its [Jump the Shark](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/series/jump-the-shark) column ("The moment your favourite TV show went bad"), but my pal reads the Sun, so maybe not.

Comment: I don't think it has to be something ridiculous - eg. a show based on the unresolved sexual tension between two characters can *jump the shark* by having them get in a relationship. It's more about the show (or anything else) doing something that changes its direction towards something that's not what the original followers came for. Sometimes it's outlandish and obvious, sometimes it's only in retrospect that you can pinpoint the moment where the show went off the rails.

Comment: I'm British and I use 'jumped the shark' all the time. It's one of my favourite expressions. British people watch so much Hollywood output that we often absorb AmEng idioms into our language, even when they don't make sense. For example, lots of British people use the word "period" to denote the final word on something, even though we already used our own "full stop" in exactly the same idiomatic way.