# What is the meaning of "a leap too far" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> Now, to jump to put all the blames on Jim seems **a leap too far**.

I heard it on street but I couldn't understand the sentence. Does it mean it is thoughtless thing to do this or does it mean that it's a bold thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bit of word-play related to ["a bridge too far"](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/A_Bridge_Too_Far) meaning "to [overreach](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overreach)" in the sense of *To miss by reaching too far or attempting too much*.

They substituted "a leap" for "a bridge" to correspond with "to **jump** to put the blame on Jim". Another example is the headline *[**A leap too far**: Will Tuckett on why his Nutcracker won't go on](https://www.theguardian.com/stage/2016/nov/21/will-tuckett-nutcracker-ballet-cancelled)*.

The story is about an ambitious attempt to make an immersive performance of a ballet which failed. Ballet dancers often do a lot of leaping, so the headline used "a leap too far" to catch reader's attention and give them a quick idea that the reason for the failure might have been because the production was too daring.

The speaker could also mean that putting all the blame on Jim is "[going too far](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go-too-far)", or is "too extreme", and the speaker enjoyed the cleverness of using "a leap too far" even though it might not exactly capture what they meant. It's difficult to say without more context.

Comment: Or **a step too far**: https://englishlogica.com/spoken-vocab/a-step-too-far-idiom-meaning-examples-k3r6m1l9dqf

Comment: @stangdon Sure, although of redirects to "a bridge too far", for example https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-bridge-too-far *(also a step/cut/adventure etc too far) something that is too extreme* I wonder which came first.

Comment: I doubt *a **bridge** too far* had any real currency before Richard Attenborough's epic  1977 movie (it needs a relatively unusual context to make sense). But ***a step too far*** and *a **stretch** too far*, for example, were common even back in Victorian times.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It does seem likely that the title of the book didn't spring from thin air. I want to make a [jump the shark](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/276656/9161) joke here, but I can't think of anything clever enough and I have to get back to work :)

Comment: I did a Google Books search for instances *before* 1977, but practically everything on the first page of results was obviously misdated references to the movie, so I didn't reference GB in my comment. But I ***did*** check "19th Century only" results for ***step*** and ***stretch*** at the time (they both had plenty of matches), and right now I've just checked the ***bridge*** version for C19 (no hits at all).